# Create a function that can generate array with only prime numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes, primitive

I was told in a JavaScript interview to create a function `getPrime(n)` to generate an array with only primitive numbers in it. The number in array has to be between 0 and `n`. How to write it correctly?

Comment: Have you come up with any option yourself?

Comment: I never used prime number before. I'd like to know just how useful it is in javascript progamming? Do you think write getPrime() is a hard question for interview ?

Comment: Fill the array with number "2" - that satisfies the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getPrime(n){
    arr=[];
    count=0;

    for(var j=1;j<=n;j++){
        for(var i=1;i<=j;i++){
            if(j%i==0){
                count++;   
            }
        }
        if(j==1){
            arr.push(j);
        }
        if(count==2){
            arr.push(j);
        }
    count=0;
    }
return arr;
}
```